# Trouble with docker pull in ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I've successfully pushed a Docker image to Amazon ECR. From my EC2 instance, I can see that image too. Now, I would like to pull that image. I did the following and the output is:

```
$ docker pull my_ecr_account_id/my_ecr_repository
Using default tag: latest    
Pulling repository my_ecr_account_id/my_ecr_repository 
unauthorized: authentication required
```

Prior to running `docker pull` command, I've logged in from the output of this command:

```
aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1
```

Comment: Are you able to describe the images?

aws ecr describe-images --repository-name my_ecr_repository

Comment: Yes, I am able to describe messages

Comment: do you run the get-login command with subshell syntax to make sure it's output is also executed?: `$(aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with Docker version. I realize the version wa about 6 months old. After updating the Docker to the latest (17.03.1-ce), it started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pipe the output of that last command thru bash or your preferred shell, like: `aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1 | bash`

or cut-n-paste the output then hit return.  The reason is that `get-login` command only produces the text of the `docker login` command that is needed to do the actual login, the `get-login` command doesn't actually perform the login.